# How do I disable flymake error for one line?

Tags: python, emacs, flymake

I am using python flymake with emacs, and want to turn off warnings per line.
I am hoping for something like

```
apa(**kwdargs)  # ignore=W0142
```

Does it exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `pylint` with `flymake`, the syntax is `# pylint: disable=W0142` or `# pylint: disable=star-args`.  I would recommend using the human readable version.  If you install the `pylint` package (in melpa), you get a command `pylint-insert-ignore-comment`, which makes it easy to insert such comments.  Finally, newer versions of `pylint` have removed the star-args warning, so you might want to upgrade.